# URL Rewrite from web.config in Azure Application does not work

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to redirect my users from "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Spa/de/#/.." to "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Spa/en/#/.." using `url rewrite` in `web.config` but it is not working. I stay on the "de" url.

The application is an angular web application deployed to azure.

I wrote the following rewrite rule in `web.config` but the redirect is not working as expected.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect from de to en" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)/Spa/de/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/Spa/en/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think there's a problem with your match. I belive this works:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect from de to en" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Spa/de/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/Spa/en/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggested match expression but it's not working either.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of caching then? I tried the rule and it works. Try requesting your URL from the command line and/or disable the cache.

Comment: I tried requesting my URL from command line using `curl -Ls -I - w %{url_effective}` 
command to get the final url after redirect but it's still not working. I'm not sure what exactly causes the issue. Caching should be disabled.

Comment: Another thing to try is to match on `(.*)` and then specify the regex in a condition as shown in the examples here: https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/. The reverse proxy example shows how to match on URL. You would not need the `negate` attribute in your case.

Comment: This actually did the trick. Thank you very much!